# Converting Days to nearest datetime format in php

Tags: php

This is what am trying to get. someone hired an  item on **2018-09-09** for 45 days. how will i convert this 45 days to the nearest datetime judging from the date of purchase(2018-09-09).

That is I need to get the **datetime** of **45** days  with **2018-09-09** as a starting point.
Is this obtainable. This is what I have tried

```
$today = '2018-09-09';

$days = 45;
$year = 2018;
echo date('Y-m-d', mktime( 0, 0, 0, 1, $days, $year));
```

Comment: `DateTime::add()` would seem appropriate. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: `strtotime($today . ' +45 days')` would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to add a pre-defined amount of days to a specific date ( which is kind of how I interpreted the question ) then you might look at using the `DateTime` class with it's associated methods, for instance:

```
$now = new DateTime('2018-09-09');

/* http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php */
$period = new DateInterval('P45D');

/* http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php */
$future = $now->add( $period );

echo $future->format('y-m-d');
```

Will print:

```
18-10-24
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
echo (new DateTime('2018-09-09'))->modify('+45 days')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Output

```
2018-10-24
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1338f3cd47840e3f321d26f711596061e93cb13)

Answer (score 0):

Use Datetime and Dateinterval:

```
$today = '2018-09-09';
$datetime = new DateTime($today);
$dateinterval = new DateInterval('P45D');
$datetime->add($dateinterval);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```